# How to make URLSession to work when app is moved to background

Tags: ios, swift, background, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

On a button click, I have to implement multiple API calls to get the data and write that data to file. I am using Operation Queue and `URLSession` `datatask` to implement this. While this API calls are in process, If the app is placed to background either by clicking home button or by a phone call, then the API calls are not processing.

I tried Operation queue and as well `Dispatch_async()` functions, but nothing worked when the app is placed in the background after API calls are invoked.

API requests should even work when the app is placed in the background. How can this be achieved?

Comment: have you tried with backgroundTask https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/finite-length-tasks-in-background-ios-swift-60f2db4fa01b

Comment: If you are doing file download, then you can use NSURLSession downloadtask which can perform background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using datatask, then you can implement backgroundTask which well explained in https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/finite-length-tasks-in-background-ios-swift-60f2db4fa01b

If you are using DownloadTask or UploadTask , you can use the configuration

```
URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:
                                   "com.yourapp.bundleidentifier")
```

Comment: thanks, @jpulikkottil. The medium article helped alot.

Comment: does the same work when the device is locked with the app running in the foreground?

Answer (score 1):

Add `beginBackgroundTask` in your `AppDelegate` class.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    _ = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your application keep processing the information in the background, you need to update the configuration from `default` to:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:
                                   "com.yourapp.bundleidentifier")
```

You can have more detailed information about this on this very nice tutorial about [`URLSession`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-016).

Answer (score 0):

try this UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { }) and its related API, hope it works for ya.